# Error when using str_replace() convert from ' to "

Tags: php

```
<?php
$str='<p style="text-align: center;">
<img style="width: 448px; height: 321px;" src="http://admin.vn/images/images/car_1.jpg" alt="">
</p>';
$search='"';
$replace=''';
$string= str_replace($search,$replace,$str);
echo $string;
?>
```

When I echo $string is result no convert from " to ' , how to fix it

Comment: where is `$str` defined in your code?

Comment: The code above is syntactically incorrect.  Reverse the quotes on `$replace` as `$replace = "'";`

Comment: Any code editor with basic colour coding (which ALL programmers should have) would show you quite clearly that you have a quote issue. Even this question shows you that, which means you didn't even pay attention to the preview.

Comment: Does the santax highlighting not ring a bell?

Comment: I'm surprised this got the number of upvotes that it did. Nothing against the OP, it's just that syntax errors usually get voted down into oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

In your original code, you were passing an undefined variable (`$str`) to the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function
I believe your intention was to pass the `$tr` variable to the  str_replace function.

Also, in your `$replace` variable, I've changed it to having double quotes (") between the character.

```
<?php
$tr='<p style="text-align: center;">
<img style="width: 448px; height: 321px;" src="http://admin.vn/images/images/car_1.jpg"     alt="">
</p>';
$search= '"';
$replace= "'";
$string = str_replace($search,$replace,$tr);
echo $string;
?>
```

Change the `$str` to `$tr` as `$str` is not defined. It will also help if you
Change your `$replace` to have double quotes

```
  $replace= "'";
```

Comment: Even though this answer is just partially correct - it doesn't deserve to be downvoted, +1

Comment: Thank you @zerkms. I relize that I didn't full address the errors in the original code, so I changed my answer to address the undefined variable `$str`

Answer (score 1):

You have the text stored in $tr not $str.

```
<?php
$tr='<p style="text-align: center;">
<img style="width: 448px; height: 321px;" src="http://admin.vn/images/images/car_1.jpg" alt="">
</p>';
$search='"';
$replace="'";
$string= str_replace($search,$replace,$tr); // Changed to $tr
echo $string;
?>
```

And make sure to escape the `'` in `$replace=''';` (or use "")

Answer (score 0):

`$replace=''';` is incorrect. You need to escape the second `'`.

Use either

`$replace = "'"` so that the single quote does not interfere, or
`$replace = '\''` which escapes the middle single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quote.

```
$replace='\''; 
// or
$replace="'";
```